# Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrResponseException

Tags: solr, xconnect

i am currently having this issue with my sitecore environment. seems to be related to solr but i can't quite understand what's wrong. any help?

```
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrResponseException: 
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "zkConnected":true,
      "status":400,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{
         "q":"id:xdb-rebuild-status",
         "fl":"*,[child limit=1024]",
         "wt":"json"
      }
   },
   "error":{
      "metadata":[
         "error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
         "root-error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
      ],
      "msg":"Parent filter should be sent as parentFilter=filterCondition",
      "code":400
   }
}
```

```
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.EnsureSolrSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.RebuildStatusWatcher.c__DisplayClass5_0.g__RunRebuildFlowCycle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.TaskExtension.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: It seems like there some problem in your Solr schema, Could you please make sure during manage-schema setup you did not perform `Set the value in <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey> to _uniqueid` for xdb indexes - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html

Comment: managed to sort this out. had to reinstall solr